# More efficient way of adding up price X quantity in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

I want to iterate through an array of items, multiplying price by quantity, and then getting a grand total. I've written the below, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way than using the `for` loop I'm using (as in, some magical one-liner).

```
test = [
  {
    price: 13
    qty: 2
  },
  {
    price: 40
    qty: 3
  }
]

total = 0

for item in test
  total += item.price * item.qty

alert total
```

Comment: I have found a way to work out that delay function. I'm referring to the question you just deleted. If you can undelete it I can post my solution there. And sorry for commenting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as OP, just tad shorter - slight adjustment with yours.

```
test = [
  {
    price: 13
    qty: 2
  },
  {
    price: 40
    qty: 3
  }
]
total += (p.price * p.qty) for p in test
```

or just a tad shorter:

```
total += p.price * p.qty for p in test
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for! A one-line replacement for my two-line `for` loop. I just couldn't figure out the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: cool, you can actually remove the () to remove two chars for little shorter expression, I just do it out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. You could do a oneliner

```
total = (item.price * item.qty for item in test).reduce (t,s) -> t + s
```

but I don't think it is any improvement, almost certainly less efficient.